# size of content database does not decrease after deleting content

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, content-database, database

I am using SharePoint Foundation server in my development environment, it has a content database with size almost 68 GB.

I deleted all the major content (media file and documents) but its size does not decrease even a single MB from 60 GB.

Deleted content from both recycle bin and run Shrink DB as well!

Comment: Do you have a RBS (aka BLOB cache) configured?

Comment: no, its a basic setup

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only reason is that your contents are still residing in SP Content database. Just verify following URL once and check whether you skipped deleting items from this locations.

```
SiteUrl/_layouts/15/AdminRecycleBin.aspx
SiteUrl/_layouts/15/AdminRecycleBin.aspx?view=2
SiteUrl/_layouts/15/RecycleBin.aspx
```

`SiteUrl/_layouts/15/AdminRecycleBin.aspx?view=2` is the second stage of recycle bin. In order to navigate to this.

- Go to site Setting
- Click on Recycle Bin

There you will find an option with **second-stage recycle bin**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Askash, second URL worked for me. Would please tell me which recycle bin is this exactly, I mean how I can reach at Recycle bin from navigation !

Comment: That's the second stage recycle bin :-). Let me include snap shot too

Answer (score 9):

Make sure that you have deleted the items in **Site Collection Recycle Bin**

[image]

**Note:**

- Once the document is deleted it moved to 1st stage recycle bin. It stays there based on the web application recycle bin setting that (default is 30 days). after this period finished (30 days) it moved to 2nd stage recycle bin it also called Site Collection Recycle Bin.
- In 2nd stage recycle bin, the document can be restored only by Site Collection Administrator.