# How to export one site collection and restore it in a different environment when build versions of the farms are different?

Tags: sharepoint-server, migration, backup, content-database, content-migration

I am using `Backup-SPSite` and `Restore-SPSite` to restore a site collection, but the problem is that I am getting the following error:

```
What is causing this error :- Restore-SPSite : <nativehr>0x80070003</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>
```

I googled it and most of the people suggest that the farm version should be the same.
The test and prod farm build versions are different. So, at this moment I cannot bring the prod to the same level as testing.

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
test: 15     0      4927   1000

Prod: 15     0      4763   1000
```

I tried to backup database and restore it in testing, but there is no disk space in E: drive. The database is something like 47 GB.
Using the database backup works for me as I did it for one content database. But as I don't have space for the second database, I can't migrate the second database and that is just for one site collection.

Any idea how to extract/backup just that site collection and migrate it to the test environment?
Bear in mind that I don't have much space to migrate the entire content database and Backup-SpSite does not work for me as there is a difference in build version.

Comment: how big the site collections are? how big the content databases? how many sites in each content db?

Answer (score 2):

**First,** the build number of the destination farm must be the same or higher than the source farm.

**In your case,**

- The Production farm has been batched with `October 2015 CU`.
- The Test farm has been batched since with `May 2017 CU`.

Check also [Find farm patch level / latest cumulative update that has been installed on SharePoint farm](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/11/30/find-latest-cumulative-update-installed-in-sharepoint-farm/)

**Unfortunately**, you can't downgrade the test environment to be matched with the production build number. **So** you must patch it to be the same or higher than the test build number. Otherwise, you will get this error

> [This content database has a schema version which is not supported in this farm](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/12/05/this-content-database-has-a-schema-version-which-is-not-supported-in-this-farm/)

---

**Second,** to avoid backup the big content database you can move the current site collection to a new content database as the following:

- In your web application, create a new content database.

  - In CA > Application Management > Database > Manage Content Database > Specify your current web application >Click create t create a new content database.

[image]

- Open SharePoint Management Shell PowerShell as administrator, run the below cmdlet

  ```
    Move-SPSite <http://ServerName/Sites/SiteName> -DestinationDatabase <DestinationContentDb>
  ```

For more details check [Move site collections between databases in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc825328.aspx)

- Now, the new content database holds only the desired site collection.
- Perform a back-up and restore to the new content database. For more details check [Restore / Migrate from SharePoint farm to another SharePoint farm using Database Attach method](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/07/17/sql-server-backup-restore-instead-of-a-stsadm-backup-restore-in-sharepoint-2010/)

> **Note:** before moving the site collection to a new content database, try first to empty the recycle bin. check
>   [size of content database does not decrease after deleting content](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/219196/size-of-content-database-does-not-decrease-after-deleting-content/)
>
> If the Content database size with only site collection still huge, so you will need to scale up/ expand your production storage!

Answer (score 0):

If there is not many web sites in the site collection , you can save each web site as a template then on production you can create an empty site collection and upload the templates to it and create your web sites from the templates.

Refer to the below link :

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/save-download-and-upload-a-sharepoint-site-as-a-template

Answer (score 0):

Install the same version cu in test environment and then use Backup-SPSite and Restore-SPSite to restore a site collection, you can download May 2017 CU the following url:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55198

Besides, here is an article to check the CU for SharePoint 2013 for your reference:

https://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=346